# Application Module abstraction in Oracle ADF framework

Tags: oracle-adf

Please explain the concept of `Application Module(AM)`  that is present in Oracle ADF framework.

If we divide a normal Java EE application into MVC layers, then which layer does the `AM` fall into? What facilities does it provide and how does it fit itself in respect to other components of the ADF framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were to talk in "regular" Java EE concept and do a parallel to JPA/EJB architecture then the AM is basically your EJB Session facade.
It handles resource pooling and transactions, and it contains the data model (VOs=named queries) that is used by the clients.

Answer (score 4):

> If we divide a normal Java EE application into MVC layers, then which layer does the AM fall into

The Application Module is part of the Model (M) layer.

> What facilities does it provide and how does it fit itself in respect to other components of the ADF framework

The Application Model defines the data model for the binding layer. It contains View object and View link definitions which basically correspond to database queries.

Application Modules can also be nested, and the root application module also provides the transaction boundary for the  application. The associated `Transaction` object can be retrieved with a call to `getTransaction()`.